# Can't use Windows.Services.Store with a WPF Net Core 5.0 App

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, uwp, windows-store

I have a C# Net Core 5.0 Wpf App that I want to publish to the Windows Store. I'm struggling to get to use the `Windows.Services.Store`, but all my attempts have failed.
My target framework is `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`.

**1º Attempt: Convert it to UWP or Create a UWP Project and then get the project reference.**

Failed because my project need some Windows frameworks such `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF`

**2º Attempt: Use `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package.**

Build error: *SupportedOSPlataformVersion 10.0.22000.0 cannot be higher than TargetPlataformVersion 7.0.*

So I found this solution: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14591. I changed the TargetFramework to `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`, removed `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` package and then build it. It says *Build Succeeded*, but the App just don't start, without any errors.

**3º Attempt: Use `Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT` NuGet package.**

With `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>` it gives the build error:

MSB3073 The command ""C:\Users\nelso.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.cswinrt\1.3.5\cswinrt.exe" @"C:\Users\nelso\source\repos\EzePunk\PuncV1UserInterface\PuncV1UI\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows\Generated Files\cswinrt.rsp"" exited with code 1.

And With `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>` it's like 2º attempt: *Build Succeeded* but don't start, without any errors.

Any ideas how to solve this?
If there is a solution for the application to run not only on Windows 10, but also on Windows 7 it would be awesome.

Comment: It's nothing special. Create a WPF project (.NET 5.0 or 6.0) and edit its `TargetFramework` as you did in 2nd attempt (to use Windows.Services.Store API). Add [Windows Appliation Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) and add reference to the WPF project. That's it. You can run the WPF app alone or create a package for Microsoft Store by the packaging project. The Store API only works within the packaged project though.